# MySQL - How to properly specify WHERE condition when subtracting values in sum from same column

Tags: mysql, sum, where-clause

I'm quite amateurish at this but I think I know the areas in which I am going wrong. What I am trying to do is create a similarity score out of 100 by comparing user ratings from a **rating** column in the **memberscores** table for each instance where two defined **userid** ($userid and $member) have an existing rating (1-10) for anything that has the same **movieid** value.

For example, ***memberscores*** has the following columns and data:

```
 movieid  |   userid   |   rating (out of 10)   
================================
   1    |     8      |    6
   2    |     6      |    10
   3    |     8      |    4
   2    |     8      |    7
   5    |     8      |    6
   3    |     6      |    8
   1    |     6      |    5
```

So if `$userid = 8` and `$member = 6` in the **userid** column, the espected result I am trying to get is `73` (out of a possible 100). Technically the answer would be 73.333333333 but I round to the nearest number.

I think the part where I am going wrong is that I'm not correctly defining those conditions highlighted below...

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(10-ABS((memberscores.rating WHERE memberscores.userid=$member)-(memberscores.rating WHERE memberscores.userid=$userid)))*10/count(movies.id)) as per
FROM movies 
INNER JOIN memberscores 
ON movies.id=memberscores.movieid 
WHERE userid=$userid 
and (memberscores.rating WHERE userid=$member) <> 0 
and (movies.genre1='Fantasy' or movies.genre2='Fantasy' or movies.genre3='Fantasy') 
GROUP BY userid
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: whats the expected output?

Comment: If $userid = 8 and $member = 6 in the userid column, the result I am trying to get is 73 (rounded from 73.3333333).

Comment: Could you post your expect result format? I am not sure your logic

Comment: Try to format the ROUND(SUM(... better. When we do queries where we select another select, we typically make it into another query, just indented a tab or two

Comment: D-Shish, based on the table example data above, the answer would be 73 because there are 3 different movieid's to compare ratings between users 8 and 6. The difference between those 3 ratings combined is 8 (8/3 = 7.3333).

Comment: But the totle count only 7, and 8/3 = 2.6666 instead of 7.3333

Comment: sorry but since when (8/3 = 7.333) ????

Comment: Sorry, I typed that at like 2am. The difference between the compared ratings is 8 as there were 3 ratings (movieid) to compare between the two userid and since I want the end result displayed on a similarity scale of 100% (where 100% can only be achieved if all ratings from both userid being compared are exactly same number for each matching movieid), the difference is 2.6666666 but I'd have the result displayed as 73.3333333333 rounded to 73.

Comment: I'm confident what I am trying to do will work if I re-do the following parts correctly...

(memberscores.rating WHERE memberscores.userid=$member)-(memberscores.rating WHERE memberscores.userid=$userid)

**and**

(memberscores.rating WHERE userid=$member)